# How to webview swipe gesture detect with multitouch zooming enabled withing a flipper

Tags: android, multi-touch, swipe

So is there a way for a webview control to detect a swipe while capable of doing multitouch zoom and having build-in zoom controls?

Comment: Nothing wrong with answering your own question, but it would be better if you could pose a question and enter an answer rather than just putting everything in the question.  This makes it easier for people to respond to your solution and to possible offer alternate solutions to your problem.

Comment: typical it's not a question.. but i'll do it.It might be more obvious that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YES!There is a way of doing that by implementing WebView and creating a custom Webview
This way the custom WebView has build in 
swipe detection  having at the same time multi touch and build in controls 
for zoom.

```
//Declaring the custom Webview and put into a viewflipper


MyWebView[] webview =new MyWebView[2];
    flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper);

 webview[i] = new MyWebView(this);
 webview[i].setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
 webview[i].getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
 webview[i].setInitialScale(60); 
 webview[i].getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    flipper.addView(webview[0]);
    flipper.addView(webview[1]);
```

and here is the custom webview

```
 public class MyWebView extends WebView {
  public MyWebView(Context context) {
   super(context);
  }



@Override 
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt) {   

         boolean consumed = super.onTouchEvent(evt); 
     if (isClickable()) { 
         switch (evt.getAction()) { 
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
         lastTouchX = evt.getX(); 
         lastTouchY = evt.getY();
         downXValue = evt.getX();
         downTime = evt.getEventTime();
         hasMoved = false; 
         break; 
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 
         hasMoved = moved(evt); 
         break; 
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
        float currentX = evt.getX();
           long currentTime = evt.getEventTime();
           float difference = Math.abs(downXValue - currentX);
           long time = currentTime - downTime;

           Log.i("Touch Event:",  "Distance: " + difference + "px Time: " + time + "ms");

           if ( (downXValue < currentX) && (time < 220) && (difference > 100) ) {
               go_back();
           }



             if ( (downXValue > currentX) && (time < 220) && (difference > 100) ) {
                   go_forward();


                  }

                 //if (!moved(evt)) performClick(); 
                 break; 
             } 
         } 
         return consumed || isClickable(); 
     } 
  float downXValue;
  long downTime;
     private float lastTouchX, lastTouchY; 
     private boolean hasMoved = false; 
     private boolean moved(MotionEvent evt) { 
         return hasMoved || 
             Math.abs(evt.getX() - lastTouchX) > 10.0 || 
             Math.abs(evt.getY() - lastTouchY) > 10.0; 
     }

 }
```

And that's It.You have Build in swipe detection.Code is in a bit "pseudocode" and haven't cleaned it up but Overriding the onTouchEvent in MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE and             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP should do the trick.You can also play with the time and difference bounds .

Comment: I tried this but it gives me a problem with zooming in/out.  It resets the webview size when you pinch zoom back to it's original size.